# Vectorized AssociateTo

Tags: evaluation, associations, assignment

With an `Association` we can update keys in place two ways:

```
a=_Assocation
(Set|SetDelayed)[a[key],value]
(*OR*)
AssociateTo[a,(Rule|RuleDelayed)[key,value]]
```

The second syntax has the distinct benefit of being able to update multiple values at once:

```
AssociateTo[a,{(Rule|RuleDelayed)[key,value]..}]
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a nice way to update multiple `Associations` at once (in place).

I would have hoped this would work:

```
a = <||>;
b = <||>;
AssociateTo[{a, b}, 1 -> 2]
(*a = <| 1 -> 2 |>; b = <| 1 -> 2|>*)
```

But it just gives me a `Protected` message and `a` and `b` remain unaltered. Similarly the docs provide nothing of note.

Is there anyway to do something like that?

This is a seemingly small thing, but it would free me from having to jump through the hoops of keeping my arguments sufficiently held in a `Scan` call and could potentially be more efficient to do many updates at once when all the key edits are the same.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a built-in way to do this but it is easy enough to implement it ourselves.

```
SetAttributes[AssociateToAll, HoldFirst]

AssociateToAll[{sym__Symbol}, rls_] :=
  Hold[sym] // Cases[ x_ :> AssociateTo[x, rls] ]

a = <||>;
b = <||>;

AssociateToAll[{a, b}, 1 -> 2];

a
b
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 2|>
>
> <|1 -> 2|>
> ```

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing now, I don't actually have that `Symbol` there because the `AssociateTo` calls are operating on an inner part of my main `Association`. You're right that it might be worth into a proper function, though. Currently just doing `Function[Null,_,HoldFirst]`

Comment: @MB1965 Sorry if this isn't helpful.  I just changed my code a little to use `Cases`; perhaps it will give you some additional ideas.

Comment: it's helpful to know how other people would do it, if there's no built in way. Your syntax is is more compact than what I've been doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are manipulating sets of `Association` objects then you may be interested in `Dataset`.

```
a = <||>;
b = <||>;

ds = Dataset[{a, b}];
{a, b} = Normal[ds[All, <|1 -> (2 &)|>]]
```

> `{<|1 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 2|>}`

Wrapped up in a function:

```
AssociateToAll[assocs_, c_ -> v_] := Normal@Dataset[assocs][All, <|c -> (v &)|>]
AssociateToAll[{a, b}, 1 -> 2]
```

> `{<|1 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 2|>}`

Even though this is not really how `Dataset` is meant to be used.

Comment: This is potentially a good alternate route. Any idea how this'll perform vs Mr.Wizard's truly in-place version? I'm adding vectorized attribute setting in an OOP system of mine.

Comment: @MB1965 I don't know.